# Ionic Back button - View does not show effect on localStorage change

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage

I have a simple requirement where out of multiple pages, I have one Settings page in Ionic app,  where I am allowing the user to toggle one data(say, language) that is maintained in LocalStorage in the app(via a factory).

This 'language' is used in all views(controllers).

I have Back button on the view but when user changes 'language' through Settings page(I update LocalStorage) and want to go back through IonicHistory back button to the preview view, change does not show up after going back.

"Previous view" uses LocalStorage.Language to fetch data

Back button uses following code:

```
 $scope.goBack = function() {
    window.history.back();
  }
```

Can anybody help here or any workaround for this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic caches views in the current navigation history. In order to update the view everytime you come to a view, you should use `$ionicView` lifecycle callbacks like `.enter`, `.beforeEnter` etc. The code written as part of these callbacks are executed everytime even if the view was cached:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
  // Get your settings data here to reflect it on page everytime
})
```

For details refer: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/